# mat-autocomplete issue with chrome autofill

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

is there a way to get the value to bind to the component when it is auto-filled with chrome but the text field is bound to the mat-autocomplete. This is my code, when I autofill the fields all the other fields work fine, but not the auto-complete one. Would I have to set the email field = to the value of a hidden field?

```js
      <mat-form-field>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" matInput formControlName="email" [matAutocomplete]="email">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-autocomplete #email="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of userObs| async" [value]="option.email">
          {{option.firstName}} {{option.lastName}} - {{option.email}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: please check version of angular.

Comment: angular is 7.1.1 and @angular/material is 6.4.7

Comment: I don't think it will work in that version.